# What was the first SFF work where magic (spells) had to be primarily channeled through wands?

Tags: history-of, fantasy-genre, wandlore

Magic Wand is a [fairly common SFF trope](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MagicWand), made ever-so-more popular by Harry Potter.

What was the earliest **published** SFF work where the trope was used?

Criteria:

- Wands are listed as a nearly-universal requirement for magic users to channel/focus their magic (e.g. doing magic without a wand may be possible but nobody or very few people are able to do so well). Specifically, this is about casting SPELLS (e.g. not potions, magic mushrooms or any other magical items/material that emit magic independently of the caster's effort at the time).
- There's more than a small handful of magic users to use them. (E.g. most Merlin-lore wouldn't usually count since Merlin is typically the only human mage there, even if he does have a wand). Let's say 6+ or 10+, although I'd strongly prefer hundreds or more.
- Ideally, this rule is **explicitly specified** in the work, by stating as an explicit rule, OR simply showing example of non-wanded mage not being able to cast spells which is explained as "because of a lack of a wand".
- A wand is a small stick-like object, possibly but not exclusively made of wood
- Clarke-esqie "Advanced technology is magic" is outside of scope - e.g., phasers or tricoders or sonic screwdrivers don't count.

Comment: Harry Potter, of course ;) but I wonder, would published folk stories count?

Comment: Do fairy godmothers count?

Comment: @MacCooper - they would (e.g. Brothers Grimm) as long as they are subject to the criteria above.

Comment: @Kreiri - if  fairy godmothers satisfy all my criteria, then yes (typically, AFAIK, there's only ONE of them per universe; and the works rarely show that she **needs** the wand, as opposed to simply habitually uses it but as far as we know could do magic with her fingers).

Comment: I would say the second restriction is more restrictive than the title question; making it a tricky question (how many are "more than a small handful"). Almost all of the lore depends of the wizards being a very small minority (since, otherwise, you would expect wizards appearing "in real life"). For example, "Willow" may or may not be an answer depending of how do you interpret "a small handful of users".

Comment: Another point, would magic potions/powder break the first rule?

Comment: @SJuan76 - Unless you're a member of an alien species masquerading, more than a handful is 6+ :) Frankly, it's restriction #3 that's the most important.

Comment: @SJuan76 - been a while, how many magic users does Willow have?

Comment: @DVK - The film had five, the book had six; Willow himself, Shalindria, Bavmorda, Fin Raziel and High Aldwin. In the book series, Elora Dannon has become a powerful (evil) witch.

Comment: @Richard - does Willow fit other criteria? (all 5-6 HAVE to use wands, and are shown to not be able to cast if wandless)?

Comment: @dvk - Bavmorda performs some pretty hefty magic with no need for a wand; http://youtu.be/AB6vUegT6Oc?t=32m45s

Comment: @DVK:   I object to your response to @ Loong which caused him to delete.   It's not off topic because:  Obviously his answer doesn't fit the criteria of 'an SFF work', but this was a remarkably good -- and I consider to be correct -- answer!    You can reasonably conclude that the notion of using a wand (rod) is so ancient that the OP's question doesn't really make sense.   Nice job!

Comment: @thepo I didn't make that rule. I'm not even in complete agreement with it. But it is indeed a site rule for a variety of reasons. It is irrelevant how well a Bible matches the question. I won't even go into theological point that deity power isn't innate magic that the question is about.

Comment: I think the OP needs to clarify what counts as a SFF work--how about fairy tales, mythological poems, etc.? What are the earliest works that would count? In a self-deleted comment someone mentioned the Circe in Homer's Odyssey used a wand to do magic.

Comment: @ThePopMachine - please explain to me - because the poster didn't - how this answer **follows the critera outlined in the question at all** (never mind being a "good" answer). Specifically, bullets #1 and #2. (this objection is 100% independent of the fact that Bible is offtopic for the site, but I just notice that you seem to think it was a good answer regardless)

Comment: @Hypnosifl - I think "published" - **bolded** in the question - is sufficient clarification. Any SFF work that's ontopic for the site and was published **as fiction** is in scope.

Comment: @DVK - I still think it's ambiguous & needs clarification. Does "published" mean any work written down copied by scribes, or any work typeset and copied with a printing press (originally invented in China), or must it postdate the beginning of a publishing industry with editors and literary agents and so forth ([this article](http://www.madeforsuccess.com/books/self-publishing-history-it-didnt-start-with-gutenberg/) suggests that stuff began in the 1400s or so). Also, would retelling of existing stories (like Grimm fairy tales) count, or must it be a new story from the author's imagination?

Comment: @Hypnosifl - to be honest, I'd be willing to accept ALL of it (E.g. written; or even oral tradition). My 2 reasons to reject the Bible answer had nothing to do with "published" status. Nor would I reject properly-fitting fairy tale or Iselandic saga.

Comment: @DVK - With your reputation score you can still see deleted answers, so what do you think of Plutor's answer about Circe using a wand in The Odyssey? Do you agree that the stated reasons for deletion do indeed disqualify it? (for those who can't see it, the stated reasons were ' I have deleted this answer because it doesn't meet all of the criteria. Circe was the only user of the wand, and she was able to perform other magic without it')

Comment: @Hypnosifl - yes I agree, with the caveat that I'm not a deep expert on Homer so I trust Plutor's analysis re: wand use.

Comment: @MikeEdenfield:   That is overly mincing words and rules.   Sometimes the answer to a question is "The premise of your question is invalid".   In this instance, the reference to the Bible is not because it is claimed to be SF (which is the problematic part) but merely because it predates.  That does **not** make that answer bad due to some perceived rules or guidelines.   If you don't like that answer, that the question should be downvoted, not the **correct** answer deleted.

Comment: @MikeEdenfield:   It's over-parsing the question, because I interpret the underlying idea behind question to be "What's the origin of magic wands in SF?"   To which I would accept the answer "This goes back thousands of years and magicians used wands since the 16th century so the intent of incorrect."   Now, maybe DVK didn't mean that at all.   That fine, that's what clarification is for.    But the deletion of the answer because **off-topic** is overly heavy handed.   The rule is in place so that religious works are not considered SF for all kinds of good reasons....

Comment: ... but that was **not** how Loong was using it.   So downvote the answer, but don't call it off-topic and thus encourage deletion.       To use your example, if someone gives the zombies-in-books answer, it should be point out that it doesn't answer the question, **not** accused of being off-topic.

Comment: Too many criteria for me to bother writing an answer, but [Faust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Faustus_(play))

Comment: @WadCheber - I only read the tranlsation and that was back before USSR fell... but IIRC Faust didn't involve "There's more than a small handful of magic users to use them" part?

Comment: [Where‘s the TVTropes Warning?!](https://www.xkcd.com/609/) *Took me eight hours to escape my browser and write this answer. Mostly because after I escaped TVTropes I was captured by XKCD*

Comment: See also the more recent https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/9069/139 "Was Harry Potter the first magic series to use wands?" on Lit SE, as well as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/193004/4918 https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/100667/4918

Answer (score 6):

A famous early example would be Homer's The Odyssey. It was a wand that Circe used to turn Odysseus' men into pigs. I suspect this is the source of the trope since the story was published over 2,500 years ago and has been widely read throughout the history of western civilization.

There's convergence here with magic potions as well. An excerpt from book 10:

> So he spoke, and they cried aloud, and called to her. And she straightway came forth and opened the bright doors, and bade them in; and all went with her in their folly. Only Eurylochus remained behind, for he suspected that there was a snare. She brought them in and made them sit on chairs and seats, and made for them a potion of cheese and barley meal and yellow honey with Pramnian wine; but in the food she mixed baneful drugs, that they might utterly forget their native land. Now when she had given them the potion, and they had drunk it off, then she presently smote them with her wand, and penned them in the sties. And they had the heads, and voice, and bristles, and shape of swine, but their minds remained unchanged even as before. So they were penned there weeping, and before them Circe flung mast and acorns, and the fruit of the cornel tree, to eat, such things as wallowing swine are wont to feed upon.

Comment: Sorry, this answer doesn't fit the question ***at all***. It fails both criteria #1 ("Wands are listed as a nearly-universal requirement for magic users to channel/focus their magic") and criteria #2 *"There's more than a small handful of magic users to use them")